# Is agm/core module not supported for angular 16?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-google-maps, agm-core

I'm using Angular 16. When I tried to use AgmCoreModule it's throwing an error. `node_modules/@agm/core/lib/core.module.d.ts:25:22 [ng]     25 export declare class AgmCoreModule { [ng]                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [ng]     This likely means that the library (@agm/core) which declares AgmCoreModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.`

Answer (score 0):

This library hasn't been updated in a while. The "latest" release still has the `ivy:false` option. This means it wasn't built to support ivy.

Angular droped the ngcc (Angular Compatibility compiler) in v16 that helped support non-ivy library.

You can also see [this issue](https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues/2036) on the repo.